# WPF Datagrid is bind to itemsource property then what datacontext is received by its datatemplatecolumn?

Tags: wpf, binding, datagrid

WPF Datagrid is bind to itemsource property then what datacontext is received by its datagrid templatecolumn?

Answer (score 1):

If you have bind `List<T>` to datagrid, then each row and its associated columns will receive datacontext of `T`.

e.g. You have list of Person, then each row will have datacontext of Person.